# If f has limit l and g has limit m, prove that the limit of the maximum is the maximum of the limits

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have to prove the following :

> If  $\lim f(x) = l$ and $\lim g(x)=m$ then $\lim \max\{f,g\}(x) = \max\{l,m\}$.

Any help about how to do it?

Comment: The limit as $x$ goes to what?

Comment: oh yes, it goes to  a, x---> a

Comment: @mtiano  i hope you can help,i'd be gratefull .....

Comment: This question does not make sense to me. If $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x$ then the limits as $x \rightarrow 0$ are 1 and 0 respectively. However $\max (f(x),g(x)) \neq \max (1,0)$

Comment: Sorry, had to edit my last. What are you taking your max over?

Comment: the excersice want me to prove that limmax{f,g}(x) = max{l,m} just with those info given: limf(x)=l and limg(x) = m. 
im  confused. x approaches a

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For any real $a,b\in\Bbb R,$ we have that $$\max\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}2.$$ In particular, then, applying absolute value properties, we have $$\begin{align}\bigl|\max\{f(x),g(x)\}-\max\{l,m\}\bigr| &= \left|\frac{\bigl(f(x)-l\bigr)+\bigl(g(x)-m\bigr)+|f(x)-g(x)|-|l-m|}2\right|\\ &\le \frac{|f(x)-l|}2+\frac{|g(x)-m|}2+\frac12\bigl||f(x)-g(x)|-|l-m|\bigr|.\end{align}$$

Note also that $\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|\le |a-b|$ for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$ (readily proved from triangle inequality. See if you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

In fact where $x$ goes doesn't matter so much. I shall just prove the case that $x\rightarrow a$. You can try what if $x\rightarrow\infty, a+,a-$ and so on. If $l>m$, then there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $f(x)>g(x)$, $\forall x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)~\backslash\{a\}$ $\Longrightarrow max\{f,g\}=f, \forall x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)~\backslash\{a\}$$\Longrightarrow$ the limit is $l=max\{l,m\}$.
If $l<m$, in the same way it can be inferred that the limit is $m=max\{l,m\}$. If $l=m=A$, then $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists \delta_1>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-A|<\varepsilon,\forall x\in(a-\delta_1,a+\delta_1)~\backslash\{a\}$, and $\exists \delta_2>0$ s.t. $|g(x)-A|<\varepsilon,\forall x\in(a-\delta_2,a+\delta_2)~\backslash\{a\}$. Suppose $\delta=min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$.If $x_0\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)~\backslash\{a\}$, either $min\{f(x_0), g(x_0)\}=f(x_0)$ or $min\{f(x_0), g(x_0)\}=g(x_0)$, and in both cases $|min\{f(x_0),g(x_0)\}-A|<\varepsilon$ holds. (For instance, in the former case, $x_0\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)~\backslash\{a\}$ $\Longrightarrow$ $x_0\in(a-\delta_1,a+\delta_1)~\backslash\{a\}$ since $\delta_1\geq\delta$$\Longrightarrow|f(x_0)-A|<\varepsilon$) Hence the limit of min{$f,g$} is $A=m=l=min\{m,l\}$

Comment: some spacing might help in readability.